# Why do I get an different hash when running with python and C# the same key and message?

Tags: c#, python, encryption

This is kind of driving me nuts. I have this code in C# which I'm trying to translate to python, but for some reason I can't get the same hash.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // input, plain text here
        string key = "8ea79bcec3d54597efe186780a835c075400623a11481d3d17dd92e905dbb615";
        string tokenHash = "st=1585258906~exp=1585261006~acl=*";
        string encoded;
        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(ParseHexBinary(key));
        byte[] bytes = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenHash.ToString()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        encoded = sb.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(encoded);
    }
    private static int HexToBinFn(char c)
        {
            if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
            {
                return c - '0';
            }
            char c2 = 'A';
            if ('A' > c || c > 'F')
            {
                c2 = 'a';
                if ('a' > c || c > 'f')
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return (c - c2) + 10;
        }

        public static byte[] ParseHexBinary(String str)
        {
            int length = str.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(length / 2)];

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
                {
                    int bin1 = HexToBinFn(str[i]);
                    int bin2 = HexToBinFn(str[i + 1]);

                    int i2 = (bin1 * 16) + bin2;
                    byte b = (byte)i2;

                    bytes[i / 2] = b;
                }

            return bytes;
        }
}
```

With C# I get this hash : 988b6a86f25529ad8a8c2da42bf95a0ca24ea113fb05fcb6e356096852693dda

This is the python code I have:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

key = '8ea79bcec3d54597efe186780a835c075400623a11481d3d17dd92e905dbb615'
tokenHash = 'st=1585258906~exp=1585261006~acl=*'
x = hmac.new(key.encode('utf-8'), tokenHash.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

With python I get this hash: 8cbb2096d5e201454bb6797b4689a524d2d7d1def51c4b66ec6b1e4a99a509cf

Can anybody tell me please where the difference is? I can't figure out how to translate it. Thankyou so much.

Comment: What results are currently you getting with each?

Comment: First thing to check, assuming you're requesting the same type of hash, is whether you're including a trailing newline in either plaintext.

Comment: I'm not adding any trailing newline. But I'm not sure what the issue is :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what python does to the `string` you provide as the key to the `hmac.new` method, but it doesn't appear to convert the hex to bytes and that is why you're getting different hashes. If I convert the hex to bytes in python first, then they both produce the same hash.

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import binascii

key = '8ea79bcec3d54597efe186780a835c075400623a11481d3d17dd92e905dbb615'
keyBytes = binascii.unhexlify(key)
tokenHash = 'st=1585258906~exp=1585261006~acl=*'
x = hmac.new(keyBytes, tokenHash.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

So, it would appear that they're not producing the same hash because the key is different.

If you can't modify the python code, then in C#, instead of treating `key` as a hex string and converting it to a `byte[]` you just get the `UTF8` bytes of the string then they produce the same hash. For me, at least.

```
//var keyBytes = ParseHexBinary(key); Instead of this...
var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key); //Do this.
```