# Why do I get an different md5 hash values between R and C# with the same message?

Tags: c#, r, hash, md5

This C# code:

```
private static string CreateHashKey(object myString)
{
    byte[] buffer = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(myString);
    var cryptoTransform = MD5.Create();
    return BitConverter.ToString(cryptoTransform.ComputeHash(buffer));
}
```

When given the string "Bangalore", produces this hashed value: "92-E7-92-78-E7-D9-37-C1-AF-AC-D7-E6-B2-CD-B6-5E".

However, I cannot reproduce this in R, playing around a bit:

```
library(digest)

digest::digest(serialize("Bangalore", connection = NULL),"md5")
```

"e85798ec7dd5003d8d464f6c5d8de5c5"

```
digest::digest(serialize("Bangalore", connection = NULL,ascii = TRUE),"md5")
```

"5377a11b9792c774ddd726361c56d8f2"

```
digest::digest(charToRaw('Bangalore'),"md5")
```

"bf19f50fed3db016cb78cdb029db3034"

```
digest::digest(serialize(charToRaw('Bangalore'),connection = NULL,ascii = TRUE),"md5")
```

"be7696c777f9418e8e853084d6ddf0ae"

```
library(openssl)
md5("Bangalore") # "1bc99cb2f4153c2d0d8025ee5575b2a0"
```

This post suggests converting to bytes would fix the problem, but it hasn't so far...
[Why do I get an different hash when running with python and C# the same key and message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893073/why-do-i-get-an-different-hash-when-running-with-python-and-c-sharp-the-same-key)

Comment: Did you verify that you have the same _input_ to the hash algorithm? The implementations can both be correct and still you will get different results, if you put in different `byte[]`s.

Comment: what **exactly** does the `serialize` method in `r` produce? from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/serialize, it looks to be a "you don't need to know" private implementation thing, in which case: you can't possibly expect to get the same result from any other platform; also note "However, the serialization format may change in future versions of R, so this interface should not be used for long-term storage of R objects." - which suggests **don't use it for this** - the results can change in future without breaking any rules

Comment: As Marc noted, the issue is your serialization. If you replace your serialize call with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(searchCriteria)` (assuming searchCriteria is changed to a string), you'll get `1B-C9-9C-B2-F4-15-3C-2D-0D-80-25-EE-55-75-B2-A0`, which is actually the correct hash.

Comment: your best bet here is probably to perform a UTF-8 encoding in both platforms, and get the MD5 of *that*; for C#: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`; for rR.. possibly stri_enc_toutf8 ? (guessing on the latter)

Comment: By serializing a string/object directly to UTF8 bytes, you'll see that JsonSerializer actually adds padded `"` on each side of the string because it has to attempt to form valid JSON.

Comment: Really useful comments - thanks everyone!  @DavidL, yes - I'm able to reproduce your "1B.." hash value in R, which you generated using the Encoding.UTF8 hashing...thanks!!

Comment: @shwan, post your solution as an answer ... ?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(openssl)
md5(shQuote('Bangalore'))
```

Gives "92e79278e7d937c1afacd7e6b2cdb65e"